# How to get the object data and only matched subarray data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have written an api to match the subarry data in mongodb, but i want to fetch only the matched subarray data and the few data of the object.

Here's my query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "projectId" : 1,
      "typesOfServices": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$typesOfServices",
          "as": "store",
          "in": {
            "sourceLanguage": "$$store.sourceLanguage",
            "targetLanguage": "$$store.targetLanguage",
            "serviceType": "$$store.serviceType",
            "rate": "$$store.rate",
            "uom": "$$store.uom",
            "typeOfDocument": "$$store.typeOfDocument",
            "tools": "$$store.tools",
            "font": "$$store.font",
            "noOfResources": "$$store.noOfResources",
            "assignedOn": "$$store.assignedOn",
            "_id": "$$store._id",
            "assignedTo": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$$store.assignedTo",
                "as": "assignedTo",
                "cond": {
                  "$setIsSubset": [
                    [
                      req.user.user.empId
                    ], [
                      "$$assignedTo"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

My Output is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5bb1ecf2d17155223c86411b",
        "projectId": "NA",
        "typesOfServices": [
            {
                "sourceLanguage": "BahasaIndonesia",
                "targetLanguage": "Avestan",
                "serviceType": "Subtitling",
                "rate": 56,
                "uom": "Days",
                "typeOfDocument": "UIStrings,Corporate communication documents",
                "tools": "Office 2016,Adobe RoboHelp",
                "font": "fgdjf",
                "assignedOn":"Mon Oct 01 2018 15: 47: 53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)","_id":"5bb1ecf2d17155223c86411d","assignedTo":["qqq1234"]
            }, {
                    "sourceLanguage": "Bahasa Indonesia",
                    "targetLanguage": "Avestan",
                    "serviceType": "Subtitling",
                    "rate": 56,
                    "uom": "Days",
                    "typeOfDocument": "UI Strings,Corporate communication documents",
                    "tools": "Office 2016,Adobe RoboHelp",
                    "font": "fgdjf",
                    "_id": "5bb1ecf2d17155223c86411c",
                    "assignedTo": []
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_id": "5bb1f36b691ae2195819b510",
        "projectId": "NA",
        "typesOfServices": [
            {
                "sourceLanguage": "Bangladeshi Bengali",
                "targetLanguage": "Avestan",
                "serviceType": "Subtitling",
                "rate": 45,
                "uom": "English Word",
                "typeOfDocument": "UI Strings",
                "tools": "Office 2016",
                "font": "fg",
                "assignedOn": "Mon Oct 01 2018 15:48:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                "_id": "5bb1f36b691ae2195819b512",
                "assignedTo": [
                    "qqq1234"
                ]
            }, {
                "sourceLanguage": "Bangladeshi Bengali",
                "targetLanguage": "Avestan",
                "serviceType": "Subtitling",
                "rate": 45,
                "uom": "English Word",
                "typeOfDocument": "UI Strings",
                "tools": "Office 2016",
                "font": "fg",
                "_id": "5bb1f36b691ae2195819b511",
                "assignedTo": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Problem is it is matching the assignedTo field but also fetching the null data(if it doesn't match.)

Can anyone please look into it, i have been banging my head from past two days. ?

Comment: what dou you exactly mean with `fetching the null data` ? Does the query return values where `assignedTo` is null ?

Comment: Your output looks broken (first line is cut off). Could you fix that?

Comment: @mbuechmann I have updated my output, please check it once.

Comment: @CristianS.  This is for matched person data i'm getting 
 (which is fine.){"sourceLanguage":"BahasaIndonesia","targetLanguage":"Avestan","serviceType":"Subtitling",
"rate":56,"uom":"Days","typeOfDocument":"UIStrings,Corporate communication documents",
"tools":"Office 2016,Adobe RoboHelp","font":"fgdjf","assignedOn":"Mon Oct 01
2018 15:47:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)","_id":"5bb1ecf2d17155223c86411d","assignedTo":["qqq1234"]}

Comment: @CristianS. But also getting this as well (which i don't want).{"sourceLanguage":"Bahasa Indonesia","targetLanguage":"Avestan","serviceType":"Subtitling","rate":56,
"uom":"Days","typeOfDocument":"UI Strings,Corporate communication documents","tools":"Office 2016,Adobe RoboHelp",
"font":"fgdjf","_id":"5bb1ecf2d17155223c86411c","assignedTo":[]}